# Can anyone let me know how to make label floating in this particular format of code

Tags: html, css, reactjs

Can anyone let me know how to make label floating in this particular format of code?

```html
    <div class="form-control">
    <label for="name" class="form-label">
        Name
      </label>
      <div ref="element">
        <input
          type="text"
          name="name"
          class="form-input"
          // placeholder="none"
          required
        />
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You can use flex in form-control class.

Comment: Hi Akib, I want to float the label on focus of input field

Comment: Try to use js then

Comment: I tried every available option but as input is inside of a div and label is outside of that div it's not working out & I cannot remove input outside of div as it is rendering through schema

Comment: on focus add class form-control or something else

Answer (score 0):

I want to make the label floating on focus of input field

```css
.form-control {
  display: flex;
  gap: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-control">
    <label for="name" class="form-label">
        Name
      </label>
      <div ref="element">
        <input
          type="text"
          name="name"
          class="form-input"
          // placeholder="none"
          required
        />
      </div>
    </div>
```